# CASE expression in WHERE clause selecting rows that are not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a query that when passed two variables, the first set is numbers 1-4 and the second set of number is 1-2. I want to select only the rows that meet the conditions. I've come up with this so far and am now a little lost on how to call the rows with my results.

```
DECLARE @Task INT 
DECLARE @Status INT 

SET @Task = 1 --Test Values can be 1,2,3,4
SET @Status = 1 -- Test Values can be 1,2

SELECT  
     Pics
    ,Title
    ,Photos
    ,Reports
FROM    
    DATES
WHERE   
    CASE 
       WHEN @Task = 1 AND @Status = 1 THEN Pics IS NOT NULL
       WHEN @Task = 2 AND @Status = 1 THEN Title IS NOT NULL 
       WHEN @Task = 3 AND @Status = 1 THEN Photos IS NOT NULL
       WHEN @Task = 4 AND @Status = 1 THEN Reports IS NOT NULL              
       ELSE NULL
    END
```

Sample data: Here is what i am using this for.

I have 2 drop down boxes, one called Tasks that hold the 4 values Pics, report, photos, title.

Second box holds the complete or not completed 1 or 2

I show all 4 Reports, titles, pics, photos when this query is called, but if i want to see all the reports that are done i can select the report value and then select the complete tab. example (Task)Report = 3 and (Status)complete = 1.

giving me all the reports that are done and still displaying the other 3 values even if they are null.

Comment: Case expression (it returns a value), not case statement.

Comment: Use AND/OR instead of a case expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the eternally simple AND/OR:

```
DECLARE @Task INT 
DECLARE @Status INT 

SET @Task = 1 
SET @Status = 1

SELECT  
     Pics
    ,Title
    ,Photos
    ,Reports

FROM    DATES

WHERE @Status = 1
AND (
        (@Task = 1 AND Pics IS NOT NULL)
    OR
        (@Task = 2 AND Title IS NOT NULL)
    OR
        (@Task = 3 AND Photos IS NOT NULL)
    OR
        (@Task = 4 AND Reports IS NOT NULL) 
    )
```

Comment: I see what you did there.. edited my last comment. very nice!

Comment: So what happens if the @Status is passed the value 2? I'm guessing that you just have the same statement below it and put an OR in front of it?

Comment: @whisk if `@Status` = 2, nothing comes back (ie, no data returned)

Comment: Yup i get that, but I'm looking to return the values null or not null based on the search. I use the value to display an image. So if its not null image1 if its null image2. does that make sense? I can explain more or edit the over all question.

Comment: @whisk Put some samle data and expected output in the question and I'll have another crack at it

Answer (score 1):

Used @JohnHC example and worked off of that. I went with a CASE after all, because it did what i needed to do. here is the finished code. Thanks for all the info and help! If you think there is another way please let me know.

```
DECLARE @Task INT 
DECLARE @Status INT 

SET @Task = 1 --Test Values can be 1,2,3,4
SET @Status = 1 -- Test Values can be 1,2

SELECT  
      Pics
     ,Title
     ,Photos
     ,Reports
FROM    
      DATES

WHERE   1 = CASE WHEN @Task = 1 AND @Status = 1 AND Pics IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        1 = CASE WHEN @Task = 1 AND @Status = 2 AND Pics IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        2 = CASE WHEN @Task = 2 AND @Status = 1 AND Reports IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        2 = CASE WHEN @Task = 2 AND @Status = 2 AND Reports IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        3 = CASE WHEN @Task = 3 AND @Status = 1 AND Photos IS NOT NULL THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        3 = CASE WHEN @Task = 3 AND @Status = 2 AND Photos IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        4 = CASE WHEN @Task = 4 AND @Status = 1 AND Title IS NOT NULL THEN 4 ELSE 0 END
      OR
        4 = CASE WHEN @Task = 4 AND @Status = 2 AND Title IS NULL THEN 4 ELSE 0 END
END
```